# isotope - Load a specific category and not ALL in the filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I am using isotope plugin in wordpress.I want to show my default filter on categorybase not a all.So

Comment: What did you already do?

Comment: i want to remove "all category" filter option from my filtering

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution.

Firstly, you have to add `imagesloaded.pkgd.js` below the  `isotope.pkgd.min.js`

Then load this placeholder js code below:

```
        var $container = $('.isotope-items');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $container.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.isotope-items .item',  //Your single item's class name
                layoutMode: 'fitRows'
            });
            $container.isotope({
                filter: '.category-1' //category class name, which you want to load for first time
            });
```

[imagesloaded.pkgd.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/4.1.0/imagesloaded.pkgd.js)